# replace specific word using regex except one case

Tags: java, regex

i have three string **app, app_abc, appabc** i want to replace any of the string with **code** (for replacing) output should be

> - app -> code,
> - app_abc -> code_abc,
> - appabc -> appabc

i have tried this **replaceAll("^app", code);**
but it will be replaced starting app

**wrong output**:

> - app -> code,
> - app_abc -> code_abc,
> - appabc -> codeabc(i want to exclude this type of string using regex)

i know i have to use or oprator 
 so i have tried this

```
replaceAll("^app|app_(?!(.*))", code);
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ils9kM/1

but it is wrong i think anyone can suggest ?

Comment: You don't have to use an alternation (the *OR* operator) nor a lookahead. You need an optional capturing group and word boundaries.

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: mr @Grzegorz Górkiewicz i have another problem please read it that was for replacing exact word but i have 3 cases do not used duplicate flag only for questions have same string

Comment: @jitendravarshney, yes ;) Flag retracted.

Comment: ok thanks @GrzegorzGórkiewicz

Comment: Negative lookahead to the rescue: `replaceAll("^app(?!abc)", "code")`

Comment: it is also selecting app from appabc which is not required @AlexShesterov

Comment: or maybe something like [`\bapp(?!\p{Alnum})`](http://fiddle.re/g5macn) (`\b` matches a word boundary, the neg. lookahead stops match if followed by an alphanumeric character) not clear if `abc` is fixed string or should be generic.

Comment: Can we say that you want to replace `app` when it is at the beginning of a string but not followed by any letter?

Comment: I'd advise `replaceAll("\\bapp(?![a-zA-Z])", "code");` or the pattern can also be `"\\bapp(?=\\b|_)"`

Comment: @jitendravarshney, no it doesn't. no substring in `appabc` would be replaced this way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are ryt your regex is working

Comment: can anyone tell what the hell is going on why downvoted me

Comment: @jitendravarshney: the example: `\\bapp(_\w*)?\\b` and use `code$1` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace `abc` only at the start of a word and only when it is not followed with another letter. Use

```
replaceAll("\\bapp(?![a-zA-Z])", "code")
```

If you want `abc` to be followed with a word boundary or underscore, the pattern can also be

```
"\\bapp(?=\\b|_)"
```

Comment: Do you recommend any in-depth Java tutorials on regexes?

Comment: Since I'm on a mobile right now, I cannot add more details.@Grzegorz,  sorry, I do not know specific Java related regex tutorials, there is regexone.com for JavaScript. A lot can be found at regular-expressions.info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String []args){
        Assert.assertEquals("code", repl("app"));
        Assert.assertEquals("code_abc",repl("app_abc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("appabc",repl("appabc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("appa_bc",repl("appa_bc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("fooapp",repl("fooapp"));
        Assert.assertEquals("foo_app",repl("foo_app"));
        System.out.println("All Good");
    }

    private static String repl(final String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("\\bapp(?![a-zA-Z])", "code");
    }
```